# Security Scanner finds XSS, JSENCODE incompatible with Radio field expecting Boolean value

Tags: visualforce, security-review

ISSUE: XSS issue in the following code, value fields will not expect JSENCODE as it expects a Boolean.

I have tried following options

OPTIONS:
`value= Boolean('{!JSENCODE(IF(ques.Question__c,"true", "false"))}')`

> Error: Open quote is expected for attribute "value" associated with an  element type  "apex:selectRadio".

`value= "Boolean('{!JSENCODE(IF(ques.Question__c,"true", "false"))}')"`

> Error: The element type "apex:selectRadio" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</apex:selectRadio>". (the closing tag already exist)

`value= "{!IF(ques.Question__c, true, false)}"`

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'IF()'. Expected Boolean, received Text

`value= "{!IF(ques.Question__c, 'true', 'false')}"`

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'IF()'. Expected Boolean, received Text

CODE:

```
<apex:selectRadio styleClass="{!ques.QNum__c}" value= {!ques.Question__c}
                                                    
onclick="javascript:showHideQuestion(JSENCODE(this,{!cs.isp__c},{!cs.isfi__c}); 
 showMsgPopup(this,'{!JSENCODE(ques.Question__c)}'));"
                                                      
rendered="{!NOT(OR(ques.IsNA__c,ques.Question__c = 'application?'))}">                                   
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="Yes" itemLabel="Yes"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="No" itemLabel="No"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Open quote is expected for attribute "value" associated with an element type "apex:selectRadio".

You're missing quotes for `value`.

> Error: The element type "apex:selectRadio" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</apex:selectRadio>". (the closing tag already exist)

It doesn't like one of the attributes you wrote, and so it couldn't find the end-tag, even though it's in your source code.

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'IF()'. Expected Boolean, received Text

The first parameter of `IF` needs to resolve to a TRUE/FALSE value (note: not `"TRUE"` or `"FALSE"`, in quotes, as those are strings). Your `Question__c` field is text, so you get this error.

`JSENCODE` isn't appropriate for `<apex:*>` elements that do not directly translate to attributes. It should only be used in literal HTML, as in:

```
<script>
let value = "{!JSENCODE(someVar)}";
</script>
```

And for attributes, you need `JSINHTMLENCODE`:

```
<a href="javascript:{!JSINHTMLENCODE(someVar)}">A link</a>
```

Also, as a general rule:

```
IF(condition, true, false)
```

Is the same as:

```
condition
```

You should only use `IF` for text, numbers, dates, etc.

```
IF(age>=18, 'You can legally vote!','Sorry, you cannot vote yet.')
```

`javascript:` is only meant to be used with `href` attributes to call JavaScript. Do not use it for `onclick`, etc.

Further, `JSENCODE` needs to be in a merge field. Merge fields start with `{!` and terminate with `}`.

Your `onclick` should read more like:

```
onclick="showHideQuestion(
  this,
  '{!JSINHTMLENCODE(cs.isp__c)}',
  '{!JSINHTMLENCODE(cs.isfi__c)}'
);
showMsgPopup(
  this,
  '{!JSINHTMLENCODE(ques.Question__c)}'
);"
```